# Java Inconsistent Logic Multiplying Hashcodes

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and trying to translate this code into SQL:

```
public class hashtest {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        calculateHashCode("asdf","asdf","asdf");
    }

    public static int calculateHashCode(String a, String b, String c) {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;

        result = prime * result + ((a == null) ? 0 : a.hashCode());
        System.out.println(result);
        result = prime * result + ((b == null) ? 0 : b.hashCode());
        System.out.println(result);
        result = prime * result + ((c == null) ? 0 : c.hashCode());
        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        System.out.println(b.hashCode());
        System.out.println(c.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

How is it that the value of the result variable flips from positive to negative in the final statement, when all hashcode values are positive?

OUTPUT

[image]

I executed this code on (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

Comment: Can you provide the output?

Comment: "when all hashcode values are positive?" nothing says that hashcodes have to be positive. But, overflow.

Comment: You have crossed the integer Limit

Comment: @Pops Do you know the range of the int in java? And what happen when it exceeds

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication result overflows, continues from the minimum value of `int` which is  -2147483648, giving you a negative result.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication overflows.

If you change the type of `result` to `long` (but cast back at the end, of course), you get the output:

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KbX9tA)

```
3003475
96111169
2982449683
3003444
3003444
3003444
```

2982449683 is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.